# JavaFX specific Audio Output

Tags: java, api, audio, javafx, output

I have a little problem with JavaFX and the Java Sound API. I want to use 2 outputs of the 
computer at the same time (USB-Headset and normal boxes). Its no problem to get all the outputs with the java sound api, but the java sound api doesn't support MP3 files.

Is it possible to configure the output in JavaFX?
Is there another solution for this problem?