# JavaFx Audio Output Selection

Tags: java, audio, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

**I'm looking for a way to specify an output device with JavaFx**

I have a similar issue as this question: [JavaFX specific Audio Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911579/javafx-specific-audio-output), but with different needs.

I need a way to **get a list of all possible Audio Output devices** (like the one you see in your user preferences) and allow the user to select which one they want the audio to come out of in JavaFx. This seems like a really basic feature that should be in any music/media API, and is essential for most audio software.

I'm using the [MediaPlayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) in JavaFx, though if there is another class I'm happy to use it. Note though that I need the same functionality for video (specifying audio output), so I need a class/solution that works for both.

If there's something in JavaFx 8 that will help, I can always wait until it is released.

***What I really expected there to be was the same thing as the [Screens](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) class:***

```
Screen.getScreens() // Gets an observable list of all screens.
```

I'm fine with hackish solutions. Really, anything that works.

Comment: Have you looked at `javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` to list audio systems?

Comment: @assylias I'm hoping not to have to use java sound, since it would be very complicated to implement with video

Comment: If you don't receive any answers, the way to get an answer is to ask on one of the JavaFX mailing lists or to create a new Jira issue.

Answer (score 1):

For years it has been a very unfortunate limitation of the Java implementation for OS X, being BTW particular for that platform, that "Java Sound Audio Engine" is the only programmatically available output audio line. In consequence, whatever you send to this line, i.e. out from any java application that you make, will always be routed to what has been set as the default output in the OS X, typically internal speakers. So the JSAE is just Java terminology for "default audio out". To our understanding - sadly - this is still the case with latest release.

Why unfortunate ? Because it effectively disables even humble audio routing. We are working with these matters on a daily basis, and it calls for all sorts of added complexity. There are work arounds, but via third party apps as SoundFlower and HiJack Pro. www.soundPimp.com for example.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or anything on how to implement one of those work arounds?

Answer (score 1):

As assylias has pointed out getmixerinfo method can help you

```
        Info[] mixerInfo =  AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    for(int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++)
    {
         System.out.println(mixerInfo[i].getName());
    }
```

You can explore further details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html)

Comment: Is there any way to get that to play nice with JavaFx?

Comment: It does not address how to use play MP3s to a specified output. AFAICT, java.sound.sampled only supports wav files.